# Installing puppetmaster/puppet server in ubuntu

Tags: puppet

I was trying to install puppet 5(opensource) set up in ubuntu 18(bionic) machines.

But i cannot see puppetserver package available in ubuntu 18 repo and  can see puppet-master package.As per puppet documentation puppet master is deprecated.Still i can  add the puppet repo and install puppetserver.

1.Is there any reason why ubuntu repo is not having puppetserver package.

2.Can i use puppet-master instead of puppetserver for puppet 5.

Comment: Have you considered consulting [the documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/puppet_index.html)?  It contains a section on installing Puppet, including specific instructions for Ubuntu 18.

Comment: The documentation is about installing the puppetserver.My question was specificall why ubuntu repo has puppetmaster and not puppetserver eventhough puppet is saying its deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah I had the same issue and answering to your questions below:

1. .Is there any reason why ubuntu repo is not having puppetserver package.  It is having the package puppetserver on Ubuntu 18 LTS bionic :

   ```
   root@test-l1-ubuntu1804:~# cat /etc/issue
   ```

   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS \n \l

   root@test-l1-ubuntu1804:~# apt-cache search puppetserver

puppetserver - Puppet Labs puppetserver. Contains: Puppet Server (puppetlabs/puppetserver 6.2.1,org.clojure/clojure 1.10.0,org.clojure/clojurescript 1.10.238,puppetlabs/puppetserver 6.2.1,puppetlabs/trapperkeeper-webserver-jetty9 2.3.1)
    root@test-l1-ubuntu1804:~#

The trick is to enable the universe repository althought you have it in your /etc/apt/source.list  with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

2. Can i use puppet-master instead of puppetserver for puppet 5 . Yes you can use the package puppet-master.. I am using it :)

@John Bollinger  - for everything is a documentation so if you do not help then why comment what you do not know

Answer (score 2):

I believe that puppetserver is the puppetlabs version and puppetmaster is the apache/passenger version of puppet.  I prefer working with puppetlabs, but it is not part of the standard ubuntu repo.  We have to wget the puppetlabs package, install the deb with dpkg and do an apt update for all machines to get the puppetlabs repo.  However puppetmaster will work fine too.